# Clarification with how GitHub's pull request works and merging in general. What must be done?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-reset, git-cherry-pick

Recently, we've been merging topic branches to our development branches. Here's the thing: right after a topic branch has been merged to development branch (thru a `pull request`), a new change needs to be introduced to that topic branch to fix some issue.

Is it okay to issue another `pull request` and let git do the rest (basically, said topic branch be merged 2x, even more, to development branch), or `reset`ting the PR and reissuing the PR is necessary in order to not mess things up? (Seems like we've taken this route, just want to clarify if this has some hidden side effect).

If `reset` is not possible, would `cherry-pick`ing be a much better solution?

Thanks.

EDIT#1:

Seems like `cherry-pick`ing works fine than usual process, but, I am concerned about its effects on the normal merging process.

Comment: I recommend just branching off the target, fixing the bug, and then issuing a new pull request.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The target being the development branch? Also, do you have any other input on the scenarios described above?

Answer (score 1):

If your development branch has no new commits after the PR, it's ok to `reset` and re-do the PR. This has the effect of keeping your commit history cleaner than the other solutions

Resetting *after* new commits have happened on the dev branch means you lose those new commits, so it's not recommended. In this case:

- cherry-picking the issue fix from the topic branch
- creating a new branch for the issue fix (Tim's suggestion)
- creating a second PR from the topic branch

are all viable solutions.

None of the above will give you a commit history (on the dev branch) where all the commits related to the topic branch are together. For that, you will need `rebase`

Comment: **creating a second PR from the topic branch** does that mean, add the commits to fix the issue on that topic branch (already merged), then issuing another `pull request` effectively merging that one(1) topic branch at least twice? Correct? If that is correct, note that that's already what we're doing... My question now is... is it safe? Ideal? Safe?

Comment: Yes, it's safe. There's no universal "ideal" choice in this situation. If you're using a PR-based workflow for the development branch (therefore not allowing cherry-picking), either choose Tim's suggestion, or continue what you are doing.